# letsencrypt/certbot - Multiple authenticators, one certificate

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'd like to use letsencrypt/certbot to create/renew a certificate for a set of domains, where some of the domains require different authenticators. Two domains, `example.com` and `www.example.com`, are hosted on Amazon S3 / CloudFront. Another domain, `api.example.com`, is hosted on an Amazon EC2 instance. I am assuming all of these domains should have the same certificate.

I think that I need to utilize the `letsencrypt-s3front` plugin (or the AWS API calls which `letsencrypt-s3front` uses), to create/renew the certificate for the `example.com` and `www.example.com` domains, along with the `webroot` plugin to create/renew the (same) certificate for the `api.example.com` domain. But I don't see any examples anywhere demonstrating how to use two authenticators at once.

1. Do I actually need/want one certificate for all of these domains?
2. If so, how do I use letsencrypt/certbot to authenticate domains where more than one authenticator is required?

Answer (score 0):

We generate separate certificates for each service such as `(www.)example.com` and `api.example.com`. For our use-case it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the OP specific use-case, using `dns-01` authentication using the `route53` DNS plugin would suffice: instead of using an HTTP based authentication that would require multiple authenticators, use a single authenticator and authorize all of your domains using Route53 - which I'm assuming is what you use for DNS for all those domains.

I have a similar use case where I'm already using `dns-01` for authentication, but I need to use multiple authentication accounts (with the same plugin) for multiple domains on the same certificate - and I don't think that is supported.